# Only accept digits in textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Given a texbox, how can I completely ignore non-digit characters? So if I press "A" or "Z", those characters would never appear in the textbox. I'd like to run a bit of code if the user tries to input digits and if he tries to input non-digits too..

Comment: How about you look to the right of this question to the links under `Related`? The first 2 look real promising

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

if `e.Handled` is set to true for non-digits no input will go to the text box; otherwise the event messages flow as they normally would.

EDIT:

To handle BackSpace and Delete is a little more work but you can try this

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles textBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) OrElse e.KeyChar = CChar(Keys.Delete) OrElse e.KeyChar = CChar(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Delete OrElse keyData = Keys.Back Then
        OnKeyPress(New KeyPressEventArgs(CChar(keyData))
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

KeyPress event does not get fired for Delete and Backspace keys and hence the override of ProcessCmdKey to manually call the form's OnKeyPress()

Comment: What if I want to use the backspace to delete some digits? Thanks so far, currently working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a test in the OnKeyPress event (or whatever the event name is in winforms)

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a "MaskedTextBox" control and set its handy "Mask" property

Comment: or use a NumericUpDown Control

Answer (score 0):

The code below works:

```
Private Sub txtSalary_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSalary.KeyPress
    If (e.KeyChar < Chr(48) Or e.KeyChar > Chr(57)) And e.KeyChar <> Chr(8) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```